# Caching issue with Google App Engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine, caching, object, memcached

I'm trying to learn how to use memcache to reduce the load on the database. So I have a *cacheData* function that caches blog posts when given a key, in this case "entries". The problem is, when I make a new post to the blog and do a database query, it returns no values despite the new post being added to the database. Why isn't the entry returning after my database query?

The cacheData function:

```
def cacheData(key, update = False):
     value = memcache.get(key)
     if value is None or update:
         logging.error("DATABASE HIT")
         value = db.GqlQuery("select * from Entry order by date desc")
         value = list(value) #returns 0 when entry is added...
         logging.error("value has: " + str(len(value)) + " items")
         memcache.set(key,value)
     return value
```

And this is the method that enters the data in the database:

```
def post(self):

    error = "You are missing a title or blog entry!"
    title = self.request.get("subject")
    blog = self.request.get("content")

    if (title and blog):
        blogEntry = Entry(title = title, blogText = blog)
        blogEntry.put()
        cacheData("entries", update = True)
        self.redirect("/blog")

    else:
        self.renderPostPage(title = title, blog = blog, error = error)
```

Comment: How big are you expecting entries to be ?  If it's over 1MB you will have a problem.  Also stuff can be expunged from memcache at any point in production.

Answer (score 0):

It could be eventual consistency problem. I'm curious, your cacheData only try to fetch one entry from memcache, and you do select * (fetch all entities). I believe if you try to fetch by key, it would be strong consistent. Another workaround is after you call .put() to persist data in datastore, also update the memcache.

Comment: cacheData isn't fetching only one entry, it's fetching all of the entries and then loading it to the front page of the blog. That's why i convert it to a list object after I do the datastore query.

Comment: Wait, I think I misunderstood, you store all the entries in a single key? I thought you store it as one key per entry. Can you try this, value = db.get(Entry.all(keys_only=True).fetch(1000))

Comment: It still didn't change anything. And yes, the entries are stored in a single key so I can display them all on the front page at once.